# Search for array values except for a list of positions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have tens of millions of documents like the following.

```
{
    id: "<some unit test id>",
    groupName: "<some group name>",
    result: [
        1, 0, 1, 1, ... 1
    ]
}
```

Result field is an 200 array of numbers, 0 or 1.

My job is to find, given a groupName, say, "group17" and a few numbers, say, 3, 8, 27
find all the document whose result array elements for the groupName are all equal to 1 disregarding the values at positions 3, 8, 27.

Would appreciate if someone could point out if there is a quick search for it.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by `...disregarding the values at positions 3, 8, 27`... since you want them to be 1

Comment: It means the search should ignore values at those positions (3,8,27 in this case), make the decision only base on values in other positions.

Comment: Ok, so it should return the document only if all values are 1 except those at positions 3, 8 and 27? What about the groups? which groups should match?

Comment: Good question!  I edited the question to reflect the input parameter of groupName.  Hope it's clear now.

Comment: And what's the mapping type of `groups`? `nested` I hope ;-)

Comment: Sorry it's not nested. Don't have a mapping for groups. Is there something ambiguous about the document shown in the post?

Comment: If groups is not nested, then you'll be unable to match on `groups.groupName` + `groups.result` at the same time. `groups` need to be nested to achieve what you're asking.

Comment: I simplified the question a little bit.  Does it help?

Comment: It was clear before, however you might not be able to apply the solution anyway :-)

Comment: Ok, was just trying to make it a little simpler so that you can come up with a magic solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is to add another field that contains the equivalent integer value of the bitset contained in the `result` array and then use  a bitwise AND operation.

For instance, let's say that the result array is

```
result: [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

The integer value represented by those bits is 1470, so I store the following document:

```
PUT test/doc/1
{
    "groupName": "group12",
    "result": [
        1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
    ],
    "resultLong": "1470"
}
```

Now, the query would look like this

```
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
        // 1. create a BigInt out of the resultLong value we just computed
        def value = new BigInteger(doc['resultLong'].value.toString());

        // 2. create a bitset filled with 1's except for those positions specified in the ignore parameters array
        def comp = IntStream.range(1, 12).mapToObj(i -> params.ignore.contains(i - 1) ? "0" : "1").collect(Collectors.joining());

        // 3. create a BigInt out of the number we've just created
        def compare = new BigInteger(comp, 2);

        // 4. compare both using a bitwise AND operation
        return value.and(compare).equals(compare);
        """,
        "params": {
          "ignore": [1, 4, 10]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2 first creates a string of length 11 filled with 1's or 0's if the current index is in the `params.ignore` array. We end up with the string `"10110111110"`.

Step 3 then creates a BigInteger out of that string (in base 2).

Step 4 compares both numbers bit by bit, i.e. the document will only be returned if both numbers have 1's at the same positions.

Note: for arrays of length 200, you need to use `IntStream.range(1, 201)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @val for the answer. 2 questions.  a) what does the number 1470 come from?  1470 is not even divisible by 8.  b) Wonder if there is a performance estimate if I have 10million of such document?   a few seconds? a few minutes?

Comment: 10110111110 (binary) = 1470 (decimal). No idea how it would perform on 10M docs (wasn't given). It would probably help to have other constraints to reduce the document set on which the script should run.

Comment: Are you modifying the document then? So that it does not require to read the whole `result` array?

Comment: I don't know how you want to handle this, all I'm saying is that at indexing time you should add that `resultLong` field in addition to the array, in order to facilitate the query. The problem with the array is that it is not directly usable in a script because it will only be accessible through doc values which will sort the values from 0 to 1, hence you lose the bit positioning.

Comment: @Val,  the size of result array is variable in length, it ranges from 200 to 500.   Not sure how we can convert so many bits into an integer.

Comment: Java BigInteger's can handle up to 2,147,483,647 digits ;-)

Comment: @reaz-murshed The result part of the document will be modified in a constant basis. Probably ten's millions of times a day.

Comment: Thanks @Val, that's good to know. Since the result array (as bits) change so much, not sure if indexing on that would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure how else you can do. one thing is sure though is that if the result arrays have different length, it'll be difficult to apply the algorithm you're after. They should all be of the same length, eventually padded with 0's or 1's... or think of another way to index your data.

Comment: Thanks @val so far. I will play with the solution and get some performance numbers.