# How do I aggregate a bit field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-scripting

I have a 60-bit (minutes in an hour) field that I would like to aggregate with a bit-wise `or` operator so that the end result is a bit set if any of the contributing values had that bit set.

The representation of the bit field isn't determined yet, but it would be nice to have it be somewhat compact as there are a lot of records entering the aggregation.

Say we have three documents with a bitfield taking the binary values: `0001`, `1001`, `1100`. A bit-wise `or` aggregation would combine them to the value `1101` - a bit is true if that bit is set in any value. Much like a sum aggregation but bit-wise operation instead.

I've considered a bit-position array (position present if bit is set) but it gets a little verbose.

Scripted metric aggregation could be possible but I'm a little at a loss of how to implement it.

Scripted metric agg would look something like this broken painless code:

```
"aggs": {
    "profit": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "minagg = 0L", 
        "map_script": "minagg = minagg | minutes",
     }
   }
 }
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54988461/4604579

Comment: Can you share a sample document and pseudo query you'd like to make?

Comment: That's a cool answer - not recognizing the scripting - looks like a java flavor? Will update the question with an example.

Comment: Yes, scripting in Elasticsearch is done in the [Painless language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html) which is a built on top of Java

Comment: I'm pretty new to it and couldn't find the functions you were using there. I'll keep looking - many thanks for the input.

Comment: The full API is available here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The scripted metric aggregation handles this. With an index with the following mapping...

```
"mappings": {
  "default": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "bitfield": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... this aggregation delivers the or'd values:

```
POST /bitfield/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "orfield": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.agg = 0L",
        "map_script": "state.agg |= doc.bitfield.value",
        "combine_script": "return state.agg",
        "reduce_script": "long total = 0L; for (a in states) {total |= a} return total"
      }
    }
  }
}
```